# An expression for inverse of inner product of two quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematics

We know:

(⟨x|y⟩)†=⟨y|x⟩

and

⟨x|y⟩)*=⟨y|x⟩

Is there a similar formula for inverse of inner product of two quantum states?
for example can we say??:

(⟨x|y⟩)^-1=⟨y^-1|x^-1⟩

or

(⟨x|y⟩)^-1=⟨y|x⟩^-1

Comment: Do you mean inverse as in the reciprocal? That is, 2^-1 = 1/2?

Comment: No I mean Matrix inverse, I know there are formulas for dagger of inner product and complex conjugate o inner product like this: (⟨x|y⟩)*=⟨y|x⟩ and (⟨x|y⟩)†=⟨y|x⟩ and I was curious about a similar formula for inverse of inner product.

Comment: An inner product does not have an inverse. The expression $\langle x|y\rangle$ is just a complex number. You can conjugate it, but it doesn’t make sense to ask for its adjoint (unless you multiply it by some operator) and it certainly doesn’t make sense to ask for its inverse.

Comment: Please note the site standard for mathematical expressions is [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true in general. $\langle x|y\rangle$ is a number, so $$\langle x|y\rangle^{-1} = \frac{1}{\langle x|y\rangle} \neq \langle y^{-1}|x^{-1}\rangle.$$

Comment: what is even the meaning of $\vert x^{-1}\rangle$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to say no. Only square matrices have inverses, and vectors $|x\rangle$ are $N\times 1$ structures. Furthermore, for any bra $\langle x|$, there can be different kets $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ such that $\langle x|a\rangle = \langle x|b\rangle = k$ for some complex number $k$. So, what should $\langle x^{-1}|k$ equal? It's not at all clear what sort of object $\langle x^{-1}|$ should be or what it should operate on.